# NSURLConnection Taking Too long time

Tags: ios

i have written this code :
  `data = ([NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error]);`

if request url is not accessible then it will take too long time and then
it will crash

if request is available then it load data

how to check faster that given url on request object is available or not and if not available then give user error .

Comment: No, you don't have to check faster. You just have to check asynchronously, and it won't crash if it takes too long. The watchdog process kils your app if you block the main thread for too long, and the right answer is to simply not block the main thread at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sendAsynchronousRequest` to avoid hanging your `UI` and set the timeout Interval if you `URL` taking too long time.

```
[NSMutableURLRequest setTimeoutInterval:10.0f];
```

Hope it cures....:)

Answer (score -1):

use "if else " to avoid crash

if (condition )
{

block of code

}

else
{
alert
}

Comment: avoid crash is not solution, it will take too long time on request and then it will timeout and application is crashed

Comment: first avoid crash and then set time interval